# A different color recording that was created over an hour ago in Apex Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I work in apex oracle, I have a table there 2 columns, ID and date, I want the difference between the date which in the table and the localtimestamp is more than gold then the entry is highlighted in gray)But I can't do it in any way, I'll be grateful for your help!)

Comment: What do you expect as output?

Comment: This will return the days between two dates |                                     
 SELECT sysdate ,
       sysdate - to_date(TO_CHAR('01/01/2020'))
  FROM dual;

Comment: There are numerous methods out there, dating back to 2007 https://tylermuth.wordpress.com/2007/12/01/conditional-column-formatting-in-apex/

Comment: Hi Apex_MAN, did you see the comments above? Is this still an issue? If so, what do you mean by "is more than gold"?